# Ruby combining an array into one string

Tags: ruby

In Ruby is there a way to combine all array elements into one string?

Example Array:

```
@arr = ['<p>Hello World</p>', '<p>This is a test</p>']
```

Example Output:

```
<p>Hello World</p><p>This is a test</p>
```

Comment: The documentation is your friend! It will help you considerably to study the methods of Array, String, Hash, etc.

Answer (score 347, accepted):

Use the `Array#join` method (the argument to `join` is what to insert between the strings - in this case a space):

```
@arr.join(" ")
```

Comment: what if you were joining digits? `[1,2,3] => 123`?

Comment: @mr.musicman `join` works with enumerables of anything that responds to `to_s`, including integers, but the result will always be a string. If you want an integer result, you can use `to_i` on the result.

Comment: If you initially broke up a multi-line string using [`String#lines`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-lines), you can sanely tied it back together using `my_string.join('')` (note the empty string argument).

Comment: To add to what @sepp2k said: `join` tries `#to_str` first and `#to_s` second.

Answer (score 21):

While a bit more cryptic than `join`, you can also multiply the array by a string.

```
@arr * " "
```

Comment: besides being cryptic, is there any possible flaw when using this trick?

Comment: @marcioAlmada No flaw, just minimal overhead. In array.c the first thing Ruby does is checking for a string type and then calling the join method. Also: pry with show-source rocks! Try for yourself: `$ Array.instance_methods.*` ($ is shorthand for show-source)

Answer (score 3):

Here's my solution:

```
@arr = ['<p>Hello World</p>', '<p>This is a test</p>']
@arr.reduce(:+)
=> <p>Hello World</p><p>This is a test</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Another possible implementation for this would be the following:**

I'm more used to `#inject` even though one can use `#reduce` interchangeably

```
@arr = ['<p>Hello World</p>', '<p>This is a test</p>']
@arr.inject(:+)
=> <p>Hello World</p><p>This is a test</p>
```