# Know the last element of array inside each

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a array of string and I want to show in my view all the elements separate by ", ".
When I do a each of this array, How to know if the current element is the last one?

Something like this?

```
- categoryName.each do |name|
  - if (name.last) -- the last elemnt of array
    = name
  - else
    = name + ", "
```

any idea!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ruby combining an array into one string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4018689/ruby-combining-an-array-into-one-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Enumerable#each_with_index](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_index) for that :

```
- categoryName.each_with_index do |name, i|
  - if (i == categoryName.length - 1) -- the last elemnt of array
    = name
  - else
    = name + ", "
```

Comment: Didn't realized you just wanted to not have a ',' on the last element. `Array.join` based answers are proper answers.

Answer (score 6):

Try to use `Array.join`

```
= categoryName.join(', ')
```

Answer (score 3):

You can simply call `categoryName.join(', ')` which connects all names in your array with the specified string. It does nothing if only one value is in the array and just returns the single name.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Rails, you can try this.

```
categoryName.to_sentence
```

It will automatically do what you are trying to.

Comment: No, not really ... `["hi", "bye", "im back"].to_sentence # => "hi, bye and im back"` : It adds the word "and" for the last element of the array.