# How to get a newline for ruby string in the array

Tags: ruby

I am trying to output two values in an array with new line.

```
list = []
list << "hello"
list << "\n";
list << "testing"
puts "#{list}"
```

This will give `hello`, `\n`, `testing` instead of the following output:

```
hello
testing
```

How can I output this array with a newline?

Comment: You want to output a single string combining the array elements?  `puts list.join` http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Array.html#method-i-join

Comment: Or if you just had `list =["hello", "testing"]` you could join with the newline `puts list.join("\n")`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ruby combining an array into one string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4018689/ruby-combining-an-array-into-one-string)

Comment: If you don't insert new-line-strings then `puts ['hello','testing']` will give you the output you desire.

Comment: just `puts list` gives what you want. don't use interpolation in this case

Answer (score 4):

```
puts "#{list}"
```

This will print the array as it is, as a string.

```
puts list
```

This will print each element of the array in new line. This might be what you are looking for.